# Function to find Max value using stringdist R

Tags: r, function, stringdist

I'm trying to write a function that finds the Max value for each row of a column using `stringdist`.

I have a line of code like this to find the max value of the 1st row but need help getting every row.

```
library(stringdist)
max(stringdist(table1$column1[1], table2$column1, method = 'jaccard'))
```

How would I write a function that finds the max value of every row in Column1?

Comment: try `sapply(table1$column1, function(i) max(stringdist(i, table2$column1, method = 'jaccard')))`

Comment: that works perfectly, thanks